# SQL server(2016) database email not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-mail

Here is the sql-server version I'm using:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3  (Build 14393: )

The issue I'm facing is with database email. After going through a lot of articles, still I'm out of luck.
Tried to reset the config as well:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs',1
RECONFIGURE 

SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
```

> 1

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail';
```

> queue_type    length  state   last_empty_rowset_time  last_activated_time
>
> mail  15  INACTIVE    2018-04-05 07:02:12.260 2018-04-05 07:02:12.247

Also checked the Alert-System under sql-server agent. All looks fine. Not sure where things are not well. Sent status reported by msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems is "unsent".
Can someone please help me out.

Comment: You need to configure your profile and SMTP settings, you can use SSMS's wizard inside Management, Database Mail (option configure database mail). You will also need to ensure visibility in networking between your SMTP server and your database.

Comment: All of this already done. Actually, I got the fix to this. actually sysmail needs Framework 3.5 which was missing. Installing this feature fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @sandeep Hi I already Enable the Framework 3.5 for Mailing but still same Issue Face as mention by you any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For me setting up framework worked out. But prior to that I also tried steps mentioned in below article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187540(v=sql.105)  . Tried to execute below bunch of queries: To check the status of mail queue here are queries:
+++
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems 
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail';  Tried to stop\start the mail-service, but still it didn’t helped.
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;

Answer (score 0):

sysmail has dependency on framework 3.5. Installing framework3.5 fixed the issue.